# objective c facebook login sdk 3.x ios7

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios7

i am trying to login to Facebook within my app using the following sample code in the viewDidLoad method...

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes"]];

//login delegate
loginView.delegate = self;

//login pos
loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), 5);

//center align
loginView.center = self.view.center;

//add to view
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

this works fine, the login web view is shown, i have authorised my app, however when i click "OK", the web view disappears and my app comes back up, but none of the delegate methods are called....

```
-(void) loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
-(void) loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
-(void) loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
-(void) loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {
```

when the loginView is initiated for the first time, the loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser is called, which makes me think it does work. But for some reason my login details are not storing.

can anyone help?
cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation
{

    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed

    return wasHandled;
}
```

I believe Facebook's handleOpenURL method actually handles the returned access token and caches the session, so it is possible that if you are missing that call the SDK may not call the delegate methods.